# how to use date picker in Pentaho Report Designer 5.2 CE

Tags: pentaho

I have created a date picker parameter in Pentaho report Designer 5.2 CE. I have selected yyyy-MM-dd as date format.

Query:

```
SELECT
     `log_summary`.`ls_schema`,
     `log_summary`.`ls_data_date`,
     `log_summary`.`ls_description`,
     `log_summary`.`ls_value`,
     `log_summary`.`req_flag`
FROM
     `log_summary`
WHERE
     ls_data_date = ${date_for}
 AND ls_schema = 'AD_SCHEDULE_PROMO'
 AND req_flag = 'Y'
```

I am getting the following error:
Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0)

I read up on Google and it means Pentaho is reading the parameter as '${date_for}'

How do get rid of single quotes Pentaho is appending at extreme ends of the parameter?

Answer (score 1):

I got it working. I had master and sub-reports in my report. So I had to add the date picker parameter to master as well as each sub-report.

If you have sub-reports in your report and you want to pass a parameter to each of the sub-report, first add that parameter to 'Page Header' under 'Master Report'. Next, open up each sub-report, right-click on 'Parameters' at the very bottom under Data tab, and select 'Edit Sub-report parameters'. You have to import parameters to sub-report, so in the import section on the left, select the parameter for 'outer Name' (Master Report) and the same parameter for 'Inner Name' (Sub-Report).